# ngModel and How it is Used

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am just getting started with angular and ran into the directive below. I read a few tutorials already and am reading some now, but I really don't understand what "require: ngModel" does, mainly because I have no idea what ngModel does overall. Now, if I am not insane, it's the same directive that provides two way binding (the whole $scope.blah = "blah blah" inside ctrl, and then {{blah}} to show 'blah blah' inside an html element controlled by directive.

That doesn't help me here. Furthermore, I don't understand what "model: '@ngModel' does. @ngModel implies a variable on the parents scope, but ngModel isn't a variable there.

tl;dr:

1. What does "require: ngModel" do?
2. What does "model : '@ngModel'" do?

*auth is a service that passes profile's dateFormat property (irrelevant to q)

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
angular.module('app').directive('directiveDate', function($filter, auth) {

    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope:  {
            model : '@ngModel',
            search: '=?search'
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<span>{{ search }}</span>',
        link: function($scope) {

            $scope.set = function () {
                $scope.text = $filter('date')($scope.model, auth.profile.dateFormat );
                $scope.search = $scope.text;
            };

            $scope.$watch( function(){ return $scope.model; }, function () {
                $scope.set();
            }, true );

            //update if locale changes
            $scope.$on('$localeChangeSuccess', function () {
                $scope.set();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Did you read about [`require` property](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-) of the directive definition object? Did you read about [isolate scopes](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-): `scope: { inner: "@outer"}`? Both are a good place to start. SO is not a substitute to reading documentation

Comment: I read these (and understand them, probably fully):

http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/,
http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope

I understand these:

    someProp: @X //will one-way bind someProp to parent Ctrl's X
    someProp: =X //two-way
    someProp: &X() //some space magic for binding methods.

edit: Looks like I didn't read require doc fully. So ngModel is generally added to require to use its methods? (Which I imagine I will find on in angular official doc).

Comment: Then I don't understand your question of "What does `model : "@ngModel"` do?" - you clearly understand that it binds a string value. And `require` - if you read the docs - allows directives to get a hold of other directives' controllers - which is used as a sort of API. For `ngModel`, the controller is [`ngModelController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController). The example above doesn't use that controller at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ngModel` is an Angular directive responsible for data-binding. Through its controller, `ngModelController`, it's possible to create directives that render and/or update the model.

Take a look at the following code. It's a very simple numeric up and down control. Its job is to render the model and update it when the user clicks on the `+` and `-` buttons.

```
app.directive('numberInput', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<span></span><button>+</button><button>-</button>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      var span = element.find('span'),
          plusButton = element.find('button').eq(0),
          minusButton = element.find('button').eq(1);

      ngModelCtrl.$render = function(value) {
        updateValue();
      };

      plusButton.on('click', function() {
        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(ngModelCtrl.$modelValue + 1);
        updateValue();
      });

      minusButton.on('click', function() {
        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(ngModelCtrl.$modelValue - 1);
        updateValue();
      });

      function updateValue(value) {
        span.html(ngModelCtrl.$modelValue);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mccDygumAzls5bPYSDEy?p=preview)

Since it interacts with the model, we can use `ngModelController`. To do that, we use the `require` option to tell Angular we want it to inject that controller into the `link` function as its fourth argument. Now, `ngModelController` has a [vast API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) and I won't get into much detail here. All we need for this example are two methods, `$render` and `$setViewValue`, and one property, `$modelValue`.

`$render` and `$setViewValue` are two ways of the same road. `$render` is called by Angular every time the model changes elsewhere so the directive can (re)render it, and `$setViewValue` should be called by the directive every time the user does something that should change the model's value. And `$modelValue` is the current value of the model. The rest of the code is pretty much self-explanatory.

Finally, `ngModelController` has an arguably shortcoming: it doesn't work well with "reference" types (arrays, objects, etc). So if you have a directive that binds to, say, an array, and that array later changes (for instance, an item is added), Angular won't call `$render` and the directive won't know it should update the model representation. The same is true if your directive adds/removes an item to/from the array and call `$setViewValue`: Angular won't update the model because it'll think nothing has changed (although the array's content has changed, its reference remains the same).

This should get you started. I suggest that you read the [ngModelController documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) and the [official guide on directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) so you can understand better how this all works.

P.S: The directive you have posted above isn't using ngModelController at all, so the `require: 'ngModel'` line is useless. It's simply accessing the `ng-model` attribute to get its value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's really a great answer.