# $watch is firing only once inside directive

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular js, so Please some one help me out.I have my template here:

```
<form ng-model="signup" form-valid>
    <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="signup.username">{{signup}}
</form>
```

And my directive is like this:

```
app.directive("formValid",function(){

 return {
    restrict:"A",
    require:"ngModel",
    link:function(scope,element,attrs){
          scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel,function(newValue){
              if(newValue){
                 console.log(newValue);
              }
          });
       }
   }});
```

When ever I am entering some value into text box the model is changing and accordingly "$watch" should fired.But in here "$watch" is fired only once when for the first time I enter any value in to text box.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want to watch the properties of your model, not only the object itself: `scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, {…}, true);`

Comment: It works for me.What is that third argument "true" is doing.Previuosly without "true" it was firing only once.

Comment: The third argument is to watch "deep" or not. eg check its the same object or check the object has all the same keys/values

Answer (score 3):

When you use `ngModelController`, the standard way for watching changes on the model is by creating a `formatter`:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
    ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(value) {
        // Do something with value
        return value;
    });
}
```

Keep in mind that *formatters* are only triggered when the model is changed directly. If the change comes from the UI (i.e. the user changes something), then *parsers* are triggered instead. So you may need to do this as well:

```
ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(value) {
    // Do something with value
    return value;
});
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hkF1p13eKqknH1Ch0LPh?p=preview)

I suggest that you read [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) documentation so you understand exactly how those pipelines work.

But if all you want to do is get notified when the model changes (you don't want or need to neither format nor parse anything), then you can do something simpler:

```
scope: { model: '=ngModel' },
link: function(scope) {
    scope.$watch('model', function(value) {
        // Do something with value
    });
}
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/whKARmvPeN6n0steEygD?p=preview)

But given your directive's name, `formValid`, I think that using ngModelController is the correct approach.

**UPDATE**

It's worth mentioning that ngModelController has arguably one shortcoming: it doesn't work very well with "reference" types (e.g. arrays, objects). More details on that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550909/ngmodel-and-how-it-is-used/29552670#29552670).

Comment: Thank you Michael.But one thing i would like to know.The moment I added a third parameter as "true" to the watcher its started watching the model.But previously why it was firing once only?The code below works for me 

scope.$watch('model', function(value) {
        // Do something with value
    },true);

Comment: @Nitya That third argument tells Angular to use `angular.equals` in order to compare values (i.e. it does a deep comparison). So if you need to monitor an object and get notified when one of its properties changes, you need to set that parameter (in exchange for some performance). That's one shortcoming of `ngModelController`: it doesn't do that kind of comparison and therefore works better with "value types".

Comment: @Nitya About the watch firing only once, that's expected. Every watch runs at least once (with undefined arguments, if the property being watched has no value), as you can see in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2qWMhOkTSH403i6k0ti0?p=preview).

Answer (score -1):

One solution would be to use ngModel like in the example below.

```
app.directive("formValid",function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      scope.$watch(function () {
          return ngModel.$modelValue;
        }, function(newValue) {
          console.log(newValue);
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Edit: The quickest solution would be to follow the comment by **Blackhole** and update your watch to a deep watch by adding `true`. This is because you are watching the `signup` attribute but the model value `username` is a property of signup. The deep watch will serve to watch the properties.

Using `ngModel` directly rather than via the `attrs`, or using formatters or parsers (as detailed in Michaels answer is a better solution in my view).

Comment: The OP is watching the content of `attrs.ngModel`, namely `signup`, which is a scope variable by inheritance.

Comment: Yes fair enough, I was was trying to make the distinction of using scope versus attrs in the link function to try and avoid confusion with inherited scopes. I'll update my answer but Michael has provided a good solution. Thanks.

Comment: Remember to accept an answer if one of them has fulfilled your question requirements.