# Angular directive watching element property triggered only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive having a watcher on an element property in my link function. The watcher is triggered only on first page loading.

The problem is that $digest cycle is not triggered since it is not an angular action, so I must trigger it manually using $interval without delay (i.e infinite execution of $digest() which is not recommended).

I haven't found a solution without using manually $digest.

There is my directive:

```
angular.module('Mymodule').directive('myDirective', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {

         $interval(function () {
                if (!scope.$$phase) {
                    scope.$digest();
                }
            });

            $timeout(function () {  
                scope.$watch(function () {
                    return element.outerWidth(true);
                }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    console.log("width changed", newValue)                 
                });

            }, 0, false)

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707489/watch-is-firing-only-once-inside-directive     this might be helpful

Comment: What are the circumstances under which the element's width would change? Just watch that instead. In other words, if it only changes when the user resizes the window, hook into the `resize` event of the `window`...

Comment: Thanks for all responses, I watched window resizing event to resolve the problem but steal not understanding how to resolve properly watching dom properties changes since $watch is firing only once inside directive.
It is a bad practise watching dom css properties ?