# AngularJS ng-model description with example?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

What is the exact role of `ng-model` in AngularJS? Can anyone explain with example? And when we can use `ng-model`?

Comment: possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419619/whats-the-difference-between-ng-model-and-ng-bind

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ngModel and How it is Used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550909/ngmodel-and-how-it-is-used)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-model` in `angular js` is basically a `directive` which binds the value of your model with the controller. Angular js Supports two way data binding which means when the value of variable changes in the model it will be reflected in the controller and vice versa. Here is a sample code which shows the two way data binding of angular js.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>

        <div ng-app="">
 
            <p>Input something in the input box:</p>
            <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here"></p>
            <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

You could find the details at [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/), [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_model.asp)